# how to change content in iframe in asp.net [VB]

Tags: asp.net, iframe

i have a problem
On my website i got iframe

```
<iframe src="www.blog.com" style="height: 340px; width: 491px"></iframe>
```

www.blog.com is outside page that contains user posts. I need to change some words (like swearing) into "#$%#"

is that possible and how? thank you.

or just how to remove that div or a like adBlock.. AdBlock removes:

```
<A class="slick_grey bolded subscribeToNewspaper" href="javascript:;" >
```

and also 
    A id="2291109" class="vote_1" href="javascript:;"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a div instead of a iframe and load the data through ajax that whay you could manipulate the content before you show it to the user 
something like

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  data = data.replace("Luck","#$%#");
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```